# MyDomain.com only provides copy-able text for Positive SSL certificate: one for cert and one for key. How do I install this on my nginx web server?

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to set up a SSL certificate on a site using nginx web server. In the past, I generated SSL certs from Let's Encrypt/Certbot with no issues. This time, I purchased a .com domain and a Positive SSL certificate from MyDomain.com. MyDomain.com doesn't provide a .zip file or ca-bundle file for the cert (i.e., there doesn't appear to be an intermediate certificate or root certificate). Instead, it gives me two plaintext lines of code to manually copy: one for Certificate and one for Key.

The Certificate line contains -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE-----

The Key line contains -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

I paste each of these lines into its own text editor file (using Atom on Ubuntu 18.0) and save as .crt and .key, respectively. (I was told by MyDomain.com support that the Certificate should be .crt, but who knows?)

I then add these file paths to my nginx site config file as below:

```
    ssl_certificate        /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/private/mysite.com.key;
```

However, nginx fails on restart and when I check the config file I get the following:

```
    $ sudo nginx -t
    nginx: [emerg] PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX("/etc/ssl/certs/mysite.com.crt") failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)
    nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Some things I've tried:

Saving the Certificate as a .pem = same error.

Manually adding the word TRUSTED to the certificate's beginning and ending = same error.

Trying to convert the file based on its encoding:

```
$ sudo openssl x509 -in /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.com.crt -out /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.com.pem -outform PEM
unable to load certificate
140561005191616:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

$ sudo openssl x509 -in /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.com.crt -inform der -outform pem -out /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.com.pem
unable to load certificate
139831375835584:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1130:
139831375835584:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:290:Type=X509

$ sudo openssl x509 -inform DER -in /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.com.crt -out /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.com.pem -text
unable to load certificate
139993835831744:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1130:
139993835831744:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:290:Type=X509
```

I'm not sure what to do from here. Has anyone successfully installed a SSL certificate on nginx using just a .crt file and .key file?

Comment: If the CA has your private key, this breaks completely the trust model. You should certainly not use this certificate and just delete anything, and find a way, through this provider or another, to have a proper setup where you are solely owning the private key and noone else.

Comment: I thought the CA is Sectigo/Comodo, the issuer of the cert, and not MyDomain.com (who I guess is a reseller). Is this not correct? Perhaps more naively, why does MyDomain.com do it this way if it so obviously breaks the trust model?

Answer (score 0):

Should anyone see this and feel curious, I had to reach out to MyDomain.com support and ask for the certificate bundle. They got it to me (.crtc bundle as well as individual files for cert and intermediate cert) and now it works just fine on my nginx server. It wasn't going to work without those additional files.